# Python : Using Shelve module how to update existing. Dat file

Tags: python

I've created a .dat file using shelve which stores the data somewhat similar to list in the .dat file.
My confusion was how to update the .dat file I've tried append since its somewhat similar to list
Please suggest your valuable reply.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to update?
Are you trying to add new data for an existing key? Are you trying to store data for new key?

Comment: Yes a new data for an existing key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be the `writeback` property of the shelve file.
Suppose you already have data for a key `key1`:

```
 import shelve
 d = shelve.open('testfile')

 d['key1'] = [1,2,3]
 print d['key1']   # data is [1,2,3]

 d['key1'].append('4')
 print d['key1']   # data is still [1,2,3]!
```

Preferably, you have to set the writeback option as True. Example:

```
 import shelve
 d = shelve.open('testfile', writeback=True)

 d['key1'] = [1,2,3]
 print d['key1']   # data is [1,2,3]

 d['key1'].append('4')
 print d['key1']   # data is now [1,2,3,4]
```

Without the writeback option set to True, you could retrieve the previous value and assign like this as a workaround:

```
 temp = d['key1'] # temp is [1,2,3]
 temp.append(4)
 d['key1'] = temp # data is now [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Yes ..exactly..the same

Comment: Writeback works in mode "c" only or in "r" mode also.

Comment: The function header is
`shelve.open(filename, flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False)` so the 'c' is the default flag. The flag 'r' is used for read-only access; I don't see why you would use the 'r' flag if you wanted to update data. Besides, you will get a `DBAccessError` if you try to update data in readonly mode.

Comment: Writeback was set to true still the append function gets executed but no changes are reflected in the existing key..

Comment: Maybe post some of your code?

Comment: I've posted my query as am answer as comment could not be done

Comment: You are passing the parameters falsely since you are wrapping `writeback` in literals. Please read the documentation carefully, you are supposed to write `shelve.open("E:\container\file.dat", writeback=True)`